# Parsing command output in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to parse out from Popen. Output looks like a table:

[SceenShotAttached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh6Bm.png)
How do I print just the col c?
I could do it easily using awk in a shell script but I'm depending on python solely now.
Thank you!

Comment: You should add the code you've tried.

Comment: I've only tried pOpen and communicate so far.. Looks like the quotes are getting complicated: rshell = self.rSc(ip, "sar -r 1 3 | awk '{if (NR!=1) {print}}' | awk '{print $4}"). Thanks!